# Google maps Javascript API doesn`t work on IOS device

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, google-maps

I add Google maps JS API on my website.

```
<script>function initMap() { var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
zoom: 17,
center: {lat: -33.8666, lng: 151.1958}});} </script>

script(async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?**********&v=3&callback=initMap")
```

On desktop map work good, only problem with IoS devices.
On Iphone I have this:
[Google maps JS API on Iphone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpW31.png)

Do you know what a problem with this?

Than you!

Comment: Would you include an English translation of the error message?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/enfk9l

Answer (score -1):

Since you're using iOS, you can use the Google Maps API for iOS directly. If you're going to use Google Maps API for iOS I think you should check the [Getting Started Maps guide for iOS](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start) so you won't encounter those kind of errors. Before you can begin working with Google Maps on iOS, you need to download the Google Maps SDK for iOS and ensure that you have an API key.

Comment: Getting Started Maps guide for iOS -  is guide for Ios app. In my case I open website in safari. For website I need use Google Maps JS API.

Comment: ok open the console of browser and look for the error. what does it say?

Comment: We don`t have any errors in Browser. In Browser map works good.